# How to set build name (Build.BuildNumber) in an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline template?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to create several build definitions, which will all perform the exact same steps. What changes are only triggers and a few parameters, basically. I therefore based them all on a template that does all the heavy lifting. That works fine.

However, I need to customise the value of `$(Build.BuildNumber)` for several reasons, some aesthetic, some practical. According to [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), all I have to do is set the `name` property in a YAML definition.

All my definitions should have the same name format, so I wanted to define it in the template directly. But setting a top-level `name` property in the template results in error message :

> /templates/default-build.yml (Line: 5, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'name'

Setting the property in the individual definitions works as expected, but won't "scale" as a solution.

The individual definitions look like this:

```
trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: ../templates/default-build.yml
  parameters:
    solution: '**/ASolution.sln'
```

The template looks like this:

```
parameters:
- name: solution
  type: string
  default: ''

name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)  # Trying to set Build.BuildNumber

variables:
  solution: ${{ parameters.solution }}
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: build_solution
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
        - task: VSBuild@1
          displayName: 'Build solution $(solution)'
          inputs:
            solution: $(solution)
            platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            ArtifactName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Am I missing something? Or is setting this particular property in a template just not (currently) supported?

Comment: I don't have an answer right now, but can you explain why putting the `name:` property doesn't scale? If you attempted to put `name:` inside the template, were you expecting the $(Build.Definition) value to be different? The name of the build definition is defined by what the pipeline is named, so in any case the pipeline that runs the build would have the same name if you had it in the main yaml anyways.

Comment: @AnthonyKlotz it doesn't "scale" because I will have a couple of dozen definitions inheriting the template and "anyone" can create new ones. I want to make sure that new ones will use the same `name` definition (which I simplified for the example) and that any changes to the format is automatically applied everywhere. Basically, limit any chances of human error.

Comment: @madd0 How’s the things going? Is 4c74356b41's answer helpful to you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: `$(Rev:.r)` seems strange to me. I suggest to **remove the dot** and write `$(Rev:r)`. See the article [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: `$(Rev:.r)` is used in multiple examples on that page @Beauty, I asked ms for [clarification](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/11941)

Comment: I created a [documentation issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/13002) for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in a Powershell task that calls the `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]` 'command'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number

The task can also be defined as a template like so:

```
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Create version number'
  name: 'CreateVersionNumber'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $newVersion = "MyVersion $(Build.BuildId)"

        Write-Host "New version is $($newVersion)"

        [string] $buildName = "$($newVersion)"
        Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to '$buildName'."
        Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildName"
```

Comment: This goes some way to being a work around, but you lose the possibility of using the inbuilt revision counter $(Rev:.r)

Comment: @housten, you can append your custom strings to the existing build number, which includes the revision: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.BuildNumber)$suffix"

Answer (score 3):

I would think that using a template for this is not supported, because `name` is a top level parameter and everything inside template is not a top level thing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline

Comment: I get what you mean, but the docs would lead me to believe otherwise. For example: _If a template is used to include content, it functions like an include directive in many programming languages._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates. I get that template references would have to be "types", but the docs are not clear in that extending a template would have the same restrictions (or _any_ restriction for that matter). (Also, it's good answering practice to quote an extract of the link that actually answers the question ;) ) cc @hugh-lin-msft

Answer (score 2):

'name' is a root-level attribute.

As stated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

> In YAML, this property is called name and **must be at the root level** of a pipeline. If not specified, your run is given a unique integer as its name. You can give runs much more useful names that are meaningful to your team. You can use a combination of tokens, variables, and underscore characters. **The name property doesn't work in template files**.

```yaml
name: $(TeamProject)_$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r)

steps:
  - script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)' # outputs customized build number like project_def_master_20200828.1
```

However you can reference or pass the $(Build.BuildNumber) in a parameter to your Template. If you are using combined CO/CD pipelines that deploys to all your environments, then the build number should be set at the top run level, as this same build is what should deploy to all your environments.