# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Add latest git tag to Build.BuildNumber

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Is it possible to include the latest git tag in the [Build.BuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variable? You can read the latest git tag with `git describe --abbrev=0` and assign it to a new variable. But can I use it in the build numbe's definiton then?

Comment: Indeed you can create a powershell set this value of the tag to a variable and then use set updateBuildnumber to perform you requested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684253/how-to-set-build-name-build-buildnumber-in-an-azure-devops-build-pipeline-temp?msclkid=b51b3d1bb19711ec8bb06724b96b1181

Comment: Did the below answer solved your issue? If yes, you could mark the question as completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command to get latest tag failed for me. I believe it is because in cases when you do not have a tag assigned on the latest commit you get an error.

You can use instead to get the latest tag.

```
$tags =  git tag | sort -V
```

Given that you have the latest tag, you can then update build number with the following power shell.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: update build number
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $tags =  git tag | sort -V
      Write-Host latest tag is:$tags[0]
      Write-Host "Updating buildnumber..."
      $buildnumber = -join($tags[0],"_","$(Build.BuildNumber)")
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildnumber"
```

*Result:*

[image]